# What would be a proper name for a custom post type created for static content?

Tags: custom-post-types

I recently divided my posts into 3 types:

Posts (blog entries)
Pages (individual web pages)
Static Content (content that goes to specific sections of a Page. For example, the Tagline).

I'm not sure if the end user will understand what static content means.

I thought about Page Content but I think Blog entries are page content too (the same as Web Content).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

On a project I am working on as we speak I encountered the same issue because the client is a bit computer illiterate / can't understand how the whole web thing works, so I asked the client what would be easiest for them to understand and they said: "Page Sections". So I would call them "**Page Sections**" or perhaps "**Inner Page Sections**".

Comment: Yeah, before asking this question I called Sections the taxonomy assigned to "Static Content."

Comment: By the way, are you doing it the same way I'm doing it:? Creating a custom post type and retrieving that content with WP_Query?(and using custom taxonomy to place the content into different sections of the page)?

Comment: Well, kind of. I am using get_posts instead of WP_Query, I tend to prefer using get_posts, but really just a preference of mine because it doesn't modify global variables, but WP_Query works too. $bottom_section = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'page_sections', 'section_category' => 'bottom_section')); Then I iterate over it using a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@janoChen:**

I think the name people often use for this type of thing is ***"[Boilerplates](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3aboilerplate)."***

Would that work for you?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Yeah, I think it is the exact term. But If I were a normal user maybe I wouldn't understand what it is.

Comment: @janoChen - How do you define a "normal" user and why would you think they would not understand this: http://www.google.com/search?q=define:boilerplate?

Comment: Perhaps by normal Jano is meaning non-programmer type users, though i'd personally never heard/read the term before seeing this question.

Comment: @t310s - "Boilerplate" is not really a programmer term, it's as much a term used by lawyers as it is by programmers. Anyway, other suggestions?

Comment: I'd probably go with something more generic sounding like "Content Blocks", "Boilerplate" just wouldn't describe the content areas appropriately for me.

Comment: @t31os - Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for design purposes then call it something like template-parts
And if its for reacuring content then call it just that.